# How to return a SQL Server view that can divide fees?

Tags: sql-server

I know this is kind of odd but I was wondering if I can do it using PURELY SQL-T script language

So here is the question, imagine we have 2 tables

```
Table purchasing
purchase_id, payment_id,  xxxx, xxxx
1            1            
2            1
3            1       

Table of payment
payment_id, processing fee, xxx, xxx
1           9
```

One payment record can be related to multiple purchase records. Kinda like a cart system that you can pay for all the stuff that's in your cart.

And I can now create a View in the SQLServer to return all the purchase record + fields in the payment table like this

```
The View
purchase_id, payment_id, processing_fee
1            1           9
2            1           9
3            1           9
```

But, as you can see, the processing fee really should be divided into 3 equal pieces, I want the view to show this

```
purchase_id, payment_id, processing_fee
1            1           3
2            1           3
3            1           3
```

Here comes the question, is it possible? And if that's possible, how?

Comment: give some sample table datas with expected ouput

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Your example output is probably over-simplified (?). Or should the *processing_fee* always be divided by number of *payment_id* rows with the same id?

Comment: @Mackan, sorry about the way I presented them. Yes, the processing_fee  was charged by every payment. So if one payment contains 3 different purchases, then, the processing_fee charge should also be divided to 3 equal pieces. Does this explains it more clearly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [OVER Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), this was introduced in sqlserver 2005:

```
SELECT 
  pur.purchase_id, 
  pur.payment_id, 
  1.0 * pay.processing_fee / 
    count(*) over (partition by pur.payment_id) as calculated_processing_fee
FROM purchasing pur
JOIN payment pay ON pur.payment_id = pay.payment_id
```

Comment: I think this needs `partition by pur.payment_id`, or it would throw an _Ambiguous column name 'payment_id'_.

Comment: @Mackan yes, you are right, corrected. Thought i had prefixed all columns already

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`COUNT(PU.payment_id)OVER(PARTITION BY PU.payment_id)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.90).aspx) to get the count of purchasing records for a payment record.

```
;WITH purchase(purchase_id,payment_id) as
( 
SELECT 1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2
), payment(payment_id,processingfee) as 
(
SELECT 1,9
UNION ALL SELECT 2,10
)
SELECT PU.purchase_id,PU.payment_id,PA.payment_id,PA.processingfee / COUNT(PU.payment_id)OVER(PARTITION BY PU.payment_id)
FROM 
purchase PU INNER JOIN payment PA ON PU.payment_id = PA.payment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but I'm not sure it's wise, since `processing_fee` is a part of the payment table, and not of the purchasing table.
Here is one way of doing it:

```
;With cte as 
(
    SELECT payment_id, COUNT(purchase_id) As NumberOfPurchases
    FROM purchasing
    GROUP BY payment_id
)

SELECT purchase_id, 
       purchasing.payment_id, 
       processing_fee / NumberOfPurchases As processing_feePerPurchase
FROM purchasing 
INNER JOIN cte ON(purchasing.payment_id = cte.payment_id)
INNER JOIN payment ON(p.payment_id = payment.payment_id)
```

**Note:** Code was written directly here, there might be some mistakes.